# Unprofessional behaviour during interview

Tags: civil-law, germany, employment

A friend of mine was in a job interview during Covid-times, therefore it was all done remotely. At half-way through the interview, an unprofessional incident happened which made that friend believe, that the last half of the interview did not go in their favor:

The 3 interviewers decided to make a short bio-break, at first the 2 interviewers went off screen, however the third interviewer turned around and apparently their pants were not closed properly and slipped including underwear off. My friend saw the whole naked bottom half of the human body.

After the pause, everyone went back to the interview and continued as normal. However, this incident could have raised an unfavored bias.

Is there any legal ground, in German law, to indemnity? Clearly, my friend has taken a lot of time and effort in this interviewing process and already was at the final stages.

Comment: This question might be more suited to Workplace. All we can offer is legal advice- workplace can offer solutions on how to deal with this and potentially hep your friend get the job.

Comment: *apparently their pants was closed properly and slipped including underwear off* pants were or were not closed?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Do you really wonder which one of those options it is or is it simply a passive-aggressive way of pointing out a typo?

Comment: Leaving out a word that turns the meaning around is not a mere typo.

Comment: I've voted to close as this question is asking for legal advice; "Is there any legal ground-work... ?" is clearly asking what your friend should do. I'm sorry, but we can't tell you what to do, we can only tell you what the law says. Your friend should consult a lawyer.

Comment: I'm unclear on what your friend wants the company to indemnify them _for_.  The possibility of not getting a job that they might not have gotten anyway?  What would the compensation for that even be?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any legal ground, in German law, to indemnity?

I am not very knowledgeable of German law, but the chances of *indemnity* seemingly are zero even if the unpleasant conduct were *actionable* on grounds of obscenity, indecent exposure, sexual harassment, etc. Also, your description nowhere reflects that the incident reasonably and/or actually traumatized your friend.

Since there was no contract between your friend and the employer pertaining to the interview, the time and effort your friend spent thereon are not susceptible to compensation.